# Retorno de dados do servidor usando Volley - Android

Tags: android, web-service, volley

Tenho uma aplicação Android que faz algumas requisições no servidor e também para envio de dados via web service, utilizando a biblioteca `Volley`.

Os dados enviados pela aplicação são recebidos por uma API e, quando há a confirmação de que os dados enviados estão de acordo com o esperado, a API retorna um valor específico.

Meu problema é que não estou conseguindo receber este retorno específico enviado pela API.
Como faço para receber este retorno e não somente o retorno `server response 200` que é recebido por padrão da biblioteca?

Comment: Eaí amigo, beleza? Que retorno é esse que tu recebe? Se for um JSON, dá uma olhada no link abaixo, que você cria um JSONRequest. Aí como resposta tu vai receber o JSON.
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html Caso não seja um JSON, Imagem ou String, você vai ter que criar um Custom Request.
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html Espero ter ajudado em algo.